# How do I style the first three items of a list

Tags: html, css

i have a table,like:

```
<html>
 <head></head> 
 <body> 
  <table class=" top-10"> 
   <thead> 
    <tr> 
     <th>index</th> 
     <th>name</th> 
    </tr> 
   </thead> 
   <tbody> 
    <tr> 
     <td> 1 </td> 
     <td> john </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td> 2 </td> 
     <td> mia </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td> 3 </td> 
     <td> james </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td> 4 </td> 
     <td> creed </td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> 
     <td> 5 </td> 
     <td> perty </td> 
    </tr> 
... and so on
   </tbody> 
  </table>  
 </body>
</html>
```

This is a list
and I want the top three indexes to have different colors
It's kind of like a hot list

How do I write CSS3 styles to make this table look like this?

[image]

yes,The code for the first answer looks pretty neat, but there's one problem we seem to be missing.No matter how many pages there are, the first three have this effect. 
How can index=1/2/3 have this effect?

Comment: Why are `javascript` and `typescript` included in the tags? Do you want the styles to be dynamic?

Comment: With classes. Can you attempt to do this on your own and then show us the code?

Comment: I think people who write javascript and typescript should also write CSS

Comment: The tag is in relation to the question, not your skill level.. This question has absolutely nothing to do with javascript let alone typescript.

Comment: Technically, that's not a list but a table.

Comment: it should be something like `.top-10 tbody tr:nth-child(-n+3)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child http://nthmaster.com/

Comment: Sorry my bad, that just gives you a range for one color.  The answer provided is the better solution.  Although how neat is it that you can do ranges with nth-child?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS nth-child:
https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

Example:

```
.top-10 tr:nth-child(1) td:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}

.top-10 tr:nth-child(2) td:first-child {
    background-color: orange;
}

.top-10 tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: If we get to page two,the index=11, i think it Is not quite right

Comment: @user4555960 then I think you'd be better off using CSS classes, as someone suggested in a previous comment.